# DB2 Iseries - dml change logs

Tags: db2, iseries

Iseries system using I/90

Is there a way to check changes made to database object like tables and views from any systables or system views or any logs on db2 for iSeries machine.

Comment: Are you looking for a system level audit trail of all schema changes or something else?

Comment: Yes system level audit. But audit is not enabled for db2. Is there a way to find out the changes. In db2 LUW we have diagnostic logs and notification logs.